# Sonar Analysis Issue on Second Mac Machine in Azure Pipeline

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have encountered an issue with Sonar analysis in my Azure Pipeline setup. I have two Mac machines configured for Azure Pipeline, and on the first machine, Sonar analysis is working perfectly. However, on the second machine, the Sonar analysis is not producing the expected results. I haven't made any changes to my YAML pipeline file except for specifying the machine name.

am user sonarqube onile